# Syntax error with upsert while using latest version

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `xguilds_relations` ( `id1`, `id2`, `dominance` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
    ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET `dominance` = VALUES(`dominance`);
```

However, this results in giving me the following syntax error:

> SQL error or missing database (near "UPDATE": syntax error)

I have been looking through Google and Stackoverflow for a while and all I found was that UPSERT is only supported since SQLite 3.24.0. However, I am using 3.30.1 and it's still not working.

What I would like to achieve is:
- Insert a new row into `xguilds_relations` with the provided `id`'s (table contains a `CHECK (id1 > id2)` or something similar) and the provided `dominance`
- If a row with the provided `id`'s already exists, update that row with the new `dominance` value

Comment: It seems the list of indexed columns is required: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b67d766a1008336d1bfd894736d8631b

Comment: Does it work with constraints/indexes to? I have some partial indexes in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQLite supports `VALUES`.  Does this work?

```
INSERT INTO xguilds_relations ( id1, id2, dominance )
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
    ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET dominance = excluded.dominance;
```

You may want to also include the columns that you conflict refers to.

Comment: As far as I know it does, but that's not where it gives the syntax error. The syntax error is given `near "UPDATE"`...

Answer (score 0):

[`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) works when there is a violation of a `UNIQUE` constraint and not a `CHECK` constraint.
Is there a `UNIQUE` constraint for the combination of `id1` and `id2`? I believe not. 
So create it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS un_id1_id2 ON `xguilds_relations` (`id1`, `id2`);
```

Now write the statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO `xguilds_relations` ( `id1`, `id2`, `dominance` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )
ON CONFLICT(id1, id2) DO UPDATE SET `dominance` = <value>;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8KkTgEgkCHgXiiwH4NPbae/0).